# How to create a facet filter that utilizes a prefix when filtering

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an attribute that is of string data type.I am using the algoliasearchHelper object to search through my Algolia database. What I want to do is create a facet filter that takes a specified prefix and returns all objects that have a value with the specified prefix inside a specified attribute.

**For example**, so far I am using this:

```
Helper.addDisjunctiveFacetRefinement("attributeName","Can");
```

This returns all objects that have the value of "Can" in the "attributeName" attribute, but it doesn't return any objects that have the value of "Canada" or "Canadians" in the "attributeName" attribute, even though those have a prefix of "Can".

How can I make it so that when it filters, it filters with a specified prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disjunctive facet refinement is used for an exact match of a filter. This is mainly used to select a certain filter out of a list of possible filters. What I assume you want, is to get a subset of all possible filters.

This is possible with our [`searchForFacetValues`](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#AlgoliaSearchHelper#searchForFacetValues) function. First this needs to be set up in your indexing settings as `searchable(attributeName)` so we can generate the additional data structures to make the facets easily searchable. You can also [read more](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search/#search-for-facet-values) about that setup in the documentation.

So once the attribute is searchable, you can use the helper function to refine the list of filters like this:

```
Helper.searchForFacetValues("attributeName","Can");
```

Have a great day!

Comment: When I use this, it triggers its own search. I am already using:                                   
     `Helper.search()` to do a search. Is there any way to make it so that I can pass parameters to the algolia search so that when I call `Helper.search()` it searches all facet values that have the prefix "Can" while also retaining other facet filters I have declared?

Comment: Search for facet values is its own separate search. It's only looking within that one attribute, so having it as a parameter would not really make sense, and we don't support that usecase (yet). I hope you'll find a way around it, or feel free to message our support with more information